# Azure YAML based pipeline can not get date and Rev:.r

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the new approach of Azure pipeline (hosted YAML file), but in this approach am not able to get date and other embedded variable.
I have a variable like below:

```
variables: 
- name: BuildVersionNumber
  value: $(Date)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(TargetReleaseBuildNumber).$(YearChangeIndicator)$(Date:MMdd)$(Rev:.r)
```

but I get this as a result

```
$(Date)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_21.570.1$(Date:MMdd)$(Rev:.r)
```

Comment: where do you put it in the yaml? under build name?

Comment: under variables:
variables: 
- name: BuildVersionNumber
  value: $(Date)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(TargetReleaseBuildNumber).$(YearChangeIndicator)$(Date:MMdd)$(Rev:.r)

Comment: It should be under `name:`, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yes, But I need the Rev and Date value for some other steps in my pipeline as well

Comment: You can't, they available only in the build name. from the above docs: "The following table shows how each token is resolved based on the previous example. You can use these tokens only to define a run number; they don't work anywhere else in your pipeline."